# Add class jquery nth

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several li elements. I would like to add the class col-md- * according to the position. The result would be as below. How to do this using jQuery?

```
<li class="col-sm-8"></li>
<li class="col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="col-sm-8"></li>
<li class="col-sm-8"></li>
<li class="col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="col-sm-8"></li>
<li class="col-sm-8"></li>
<li class="col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="col-sm-4"></li>
```

Comment: if I may, pls show us something that you've tried and didn't work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Google "nth-child selectors" and give that a shot.  Then ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the selector `4n+2` and add the next LI to that collection, add the class, and then just store that selection to exclude it when adding the other class

```js
var sm4 = $('ul li:nth-child(4n+2)').next('li').addBack().addClass("col-sm-4");
$('ul li').not(sm4).addClass("col-sm-8")
```

```css
.col-sm-8 {color : red}
.col-sm-4 {color : blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```